# Copying files into certain directories based on filename

Tags: powershell, batch

I don't really have any real touchpoints with Batch or PowerShell, nevertheless, I have set up an employee directory for which I am now looking for a solution, where documents are automatically copied into the aforementioned directory via a script:

- The documents to be copied are currently all in one folder and should be copied into the respective subfolder of the directory.
- The file names of the documents are structured as follows, where `XX` / `XXXX` are the variables that play a role in the assignment:

  - `ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_XX.pdf` 
     `ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_XXXX.pdf`
- The target directories also contain these, currently with about fifty different ones

Is it possible to only point to the variables between the third underscore and file extension, as these vary, possibly with adding a three or five-digit variable?

- I have already used the search function, but found nothing that exactly corresponds to the given example:

  - `C:\ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_99` → `\\11/17/19/1991\Directory\99_ABCD\` 
     `C:\ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_9999` → `\\11/17/19/1991\Directory\9999_ABCD\`
  - Possibly: 
     `C:\ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_999` → `\\11/17/19/1991\ directory\999_ABCD\` 
     `C:\ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_99999` → `\\11/17/19/1991\Directory\99999_ABCD\`

I've tried to set this up with `$FileName-split`, which didn't really work out, but I've managed to complete the filenames to actually count it up, as in 30:27:

- `C:\ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_99` → `C:\ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_0099`
- I'm struggling with parsing the destination folders, with all folders existing and variables in their filenames, getting this far:

  ```
  $Directory = "C:\Folder\" 
  $FileNames = (Get-Item $Directory).GetFiles()

  foreach($FileName in $FileNames) {
    $Destination = "\\10.10.10.10\destinationfolder"
    { Move-Item -Path $FileName -Destination $Destination }
  }
  ```

Is there a way to move the files by match or do I have to parse all destination folders by counting as well so the part to be checked is set?

This may visualize it

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: The post is unclear. Can you include your exact rules regarding file-names and folders?

Comment: Theres a record of 50 files. 
e.g. 
ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_0001.filext
ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_0002.filext
ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_0011.filext
ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_0022.filext
ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_1111.filext
etc.
and a record of 50 Folders, names containing the variables.
e.g. 0001_ABCD
0002_ABCD
0011_ABCD
I'm trying to sort those to each other based on matching of those variables.
The Files are all in C:/folder and supposed to go to \\10.10.10.10\destinationfolder\0001_ABCD as example. Files are recurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a PowerShell solution:

```
$Destination = "\\10.10.10.10\destinationfolder"
Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder" | ForEach-Object {
    $Head = ($_.BaseName -split '_')[0]
    $Tail = ($_.BaseName -split '_')[-1]
    $DestinationPath = Join-Path $Destination ("{0}_{1}" -f $Head, $Tail)
    New-Item -Path $DestinationPath -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Copy-Item $_.FullName $DestinationPath -Force
}
```

Update:

Following your comments, I guess this is more what you want. However, you have to be sure, that each ending has exactly one folder that matches. e.g if there is a folder that's called `abc_123` and another that's called `def_123` it will simply take the first one, because as of your comments, we only take the ending into consideration

```
$Destination = "\\10.10.10.10\destinationfolder"
Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder" | ForEach-Object {
    $Tail = ($_.BaseName -split '_')[-1]
    $Filter = "*_{0}" -f $Tail
    $DestDir = Get-ChildItem $Destination -Filter $Filter -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName -First 1
    if ($DestDir) {
        Copy-Item $_.FullName $DestDir -Force
    } else {
        "No Directory was found that matched the Filter {0} in Directory {1}" -f $Filter, $Destination | Write-Host
    }
}
```

It does the following:

- First set the destination folder in the `$Destination` Variable
- Get All Items in a folder with `Get-ChildItem` (if you need to make this recursive, add the `-Recurse` switch, if you only want certain Filetypes add `-Filter *.txt` or any other extension)
- loop over all found files with `ForEach-Object`
- split the Basename (that's the filename without extension) on `_` and get the last part of the Basename and save it in the `$Ending` Variable
- Calculate the foldername by format the Ending Variable to a foldername with `-f`
- Use `Join-Path` to connect the Destination and the calculated folder and save it in `$Destinationpath`
- Create the folder if it does not exist with `New-Item`. If it already does exist this line does not overwrite the existing folder
- Copy the item to the destination folder with `Copy-Item`

Comment: if you also need a dynamic "head" for your directoryname, look at keith's answer, he's shown you how to do that there (`-split [0]`)

Comment: Thanks alot, this works like a charm, but i dont want it to create new folders, neither the ABCD is playing a role. Its supposed to point to the variable numbers only. Would this be the case when removing the ABCD_{0} and adding a dynamic head?
Just so whatever the name of the destination folder infront of the _$Ending is, it is gonna copy the Files with matching Ending in it.

Comment: The Description really helped me understanding though

Comment: @BlackArch.py you mean e.g you have a file that's called `ABC_xyz_123.txt` and for example a folder thats called `fgh_123` you want that file to go in there because we only have to look for the ending (which consists of one `_` and after that the digits) and we don't have to mind for the beginning?

Comment: Exactly, how do i put like a variable for the whole prefix (characters before the_) of the folder the file is going into? Or is there another solution? You got what i meant though!

Comment: @BlackArch.py check my update.

Comment: im trying to run $Tail with [-2] but keep getting errors. Wheres Disk "@{FullName=C" set?. Also im running into Format Errors. Index based on 0 has to be ≥ null and < than argument list. Whats that about?

Comment: why [-2] what do you want to achieve? everything should be fine now. I had a small error on the Fullname stuff, now it should work with the updated code.

Comment: Yh it fixed the Fulldisk error but im still getting the other one mentioned above ; InvalidOperation: (*_{1}:String) [], RuntimeException. Well im trying to use the -2 split as $ tail, wouldnt that work out ?

Comment: @BlackArch.py uff another thing i forgot to change. it should've been {0} instead of {1}. What about now?

Comment: It really confuses things when you do a wholesale lift of my code without mention. No wonder the OP is confused.! I have trouble scroll thruogh knowing which is which!

Comment: @KeithMiller I don't know what a wholesale lift is, but what I do know is that you beat me to it by posting your answer 3 minutes before i posted mine (and while i was writing mine, so I didn't see you posted until i finished mine). So if wholesale lift means that i copied your answer that is not true, we simply had very similar answers - which is a good thing because that means that's the way to go! Almost a little hurting, that you even suggest that I would do such things, for such simple code. I always try to keep my integrity and professionality.

Comment: @SimonS:  If you scroll thru this question now, our code blocks look very similar. If we look at your original code, the variables `$Head` & `Tail` are nowhre to be seen (I suppose imitation is the sincerest form of flattery). You hadn't even read the question carefully enough to extract the strings needed to construct the subfolder names -- that's somewhat critcal. The OP's failure to update the main question doesn't help!

Answer (score 1):

i don't understand your question but if you want to copy and paste file like this

```
ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_1.txt copy into 1_ABCD
ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_2.txt copy into 2_ABCD
ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_3.txt copy into 3_ABCD
ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_9999.txt copy into 9999_ABCD
```

Then maybe this cmd command can help you

```
echo D|for /l %x in (1,1,20) do @xcopy ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_%x.txt ABC_%x\ /Y /Q
```

second command with same output:

```
for /l %x in (1,1,20) do @xcopy ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_%x.txt ABC_%x\ /Y /Q
```

you can change `20` to `9999`
[image: output]

This Command will create a folder if not exists and then paste the file and if file is existed inside a folder it will overwrite the file

**UPDATE:**

**Command to Find files name without extension** (and Append result into filenamewithoutext.txt)

```
for /f %x in ('dir /b') do @echo %~nx>>filenamewithoutext.txt
```

**Reading output file and saving variables into new file** `variables.txt`

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims=_" %x in (filenamewithoutext.txt) do @echo %x>>variables.txt
```

**Reading Variables and copying files into different folders**

```
for /f %x in (variables.txt) do @xcopy ABCD_123456_1234567_12345_%x.txt ABC_%x\ /Y /Q
```

you can change `ABC_%x` to `%x_ABC`

Comment: Thanks alot, your Solution is going the right way, but the foldername is 
continuously always a different one e.g. ABC in the foldername equals different names so this wont work out if i got that right. Thats why im trying to **only** point to the variables to match them, if you get what i mean. Everything but those variables is always different.

Comment: Updated my answer check ```Update``` section

Comment: Thanks alot. Might get that wrong but it wont work out. Its 50 different Files and 50 different folders. ABCD_123456_1234567_12345 is a example for continuously changing parameters. The only characters staying the same for each 50 is their variables. Nothing but those is to be used cause everything else keeps on changing.
For your understanding, Within the filename theres billing numbers etc. which keep on changing per file, the only parameter staying the same is XX/XXXX which is the employee number at the end. The folders are named employeenumber_employee.

Comment: Thats why im saying the script should only point to 27:30 or between _ and .fileext or in case of the folders 1:2 / before the underscore

Answer (score 1):

As I read your question, I think this should work:

```
$Source      = 'C:\Folder\'
$Destination = '\\10.10.10.10\destinationfolder\'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -FIlter *.pdf -File | ? { ($BaseName = $_.BaseName) -match '_' } | ForEach{
    $Head       = $BaseName.Split('_')[0]
    $Tail       = $BaseName.Split('_')[-1]       ### (Index of -1) -> Last array element
    $SubFolder  = "$Tail`_$Head"                 ### *** Escaped <underscore> required ***
    If ( Test-Path ( $FullPath = Join-Path $Destination $SubFolder ) ) {
        Copy-Item -Literal $_.FullName $FullPath
    } Else {
        '"{0}" not copied because the directory "{1}" does not exist' -f $_.Name , $FullPath | Write-Output
    }
}
```

[ForEach-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)  •  [String.Split() method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0)  •  [Join-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7.1)  •  [Test-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path)  •  [Copy-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1)

---

### Debugging

I used this variation of the code to troubleshoot the string manipulation, which uncovered the issue of using an underscore in expansion strings. Puts all the intermediate variables in a **`GridView`** for quick scanning:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -FIlter *.pdf -File | ? BaseName -match '_' | ForEach{
    $Head       = $_.BaseName.Split('_')[0]
    $Tail       = $_.BaseName.Split('_')[-1]
    $SubFolder  = "$Tail`_$Head"
    $FullPath   = Join-Path $Destination $SubFolder

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Head'       = $Head
        'Tail'       = $Tail
        'SubFolder'  = $SubFolder
        'FullPath'   = $FullPath
        'SubExists'  = Test-Path $FullPath
    }
} | Out-gridview
```

### Optimization

Intermediate variables are great during development/testing/debugging, but can slow things down inside a loop executed this many times. So, once the assignments seeed to be robust, I worked my way backwards, first copying the expression defining `$SubFolder` to the clipboard, then replacing `$SubFolder`'s occurance in `$FullPath = ...` with its definition enclosed in parentheses, then dis the same for the variables within that definition. Also combined assignment with first use. The result was:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -FIlter *.pdf -File | ForEach{
If ( ($BaseName = $_.BaseName) -match '_' ) {
        If ( Test-Path ( $FullPath=Join-Path $Destination "$($BaseName.Split('_')[-1])`_$($BaseName.Split('_')[0])" ) ) {
            Copy-Item -Literal $_.FullName $FullPath
        } Else {
            '"{0}" not copied because the directory "{1}" does not exist' -f $_.Name , $FullPath | Write-Output
        }
    }
}
```

Hell to read, but should be worth it for large data sets.

Comment: This seemed like exactly what i was looking for but wont work out. Thanks for your work though. I might be able to complete it with yours and Simons Script, cause those helped me get some understanding.

Comment: I see mention of "27:30" in the OP but it's in various comments -- where is that coming from? ***Update theo OP!!!*** Half the OP says `copy` & half `move` SimonS comfused things by lifting my code wholesale and modifying.

Comment: @KeithMiller As I said in the other comment. I did not lift your code. I wrote my code myself. I write every code myself I post on this site. You're saying this out of the blue, without checking the timestamps at all. I cannot take your code, "lift" it, and write a full explanation of everything that's happening in 3 minutes, which is the timespan your answer and my answer were posted apart. As for confusing, i don't think anyone is confused.

Comment: @SimonS: When you are going blind and have to zoom the browser to 150-200% and use Magnifier on top of that, you can't take in a lot at one time, so seeing `$Head = $_.BaseName.Split('_')[0]` & `$Tail = $_.BaseName.Split('_')[-1]`  -- identical to my statements, can be confusing.